# How to remove specific class using php

Tags: php

How to remove 2nd **'a'** tag or class ('touch') and content using php?
I am looking for index option but how to do that?

```
  $strings = '<a class="touch">1</a>           
              <a class="touch">2</a>
              <a class="touch">3</a>';

   $output = preg_replace('#<a(.*?)</a>#is', '', $strings);

   echo $output;
```

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML/XML with regular expressions. Use DOM, SimpleXML, or similar extensions instead.

Comment: read/translate this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See updated question.